# Laravel : transforming a request into another

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request

I want to log my users as soon as they register. here's my UserController's code (which works) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\Login;
use App\Http\Requests\Register;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Register $request)
    {
        User::create($request->all());

        $loginRequest             = new Login();
        $loginRequest['email']    = $request->get('email');
        $loginRequest['password'] = $request->get('password');

        return $this->login($loginRequest);
    }

    public function login(Login $request)
    {
        return 'ok';
    }
}
```

I feel I'm doing something ugly with my `$loginRequest`. Is there a neater way to do the same ? Aka transform my Register request into a Login request ?

Comment: I know it's a irrelevant comment but why don't you just use laravel authentication ? All you need to say `php artisan make:auth` and laravel handle with rest

Comment: what is the point of `Request\Login` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You are simply trying to logged in user into his account after the registration so use `Auth::login($user)`

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Register $request)
    {
        $user =  User::create($request->all());

       \Auth::login($user);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as user register you can use this snippet of code to attempt a login

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {

return Redirect::route('dashboard');
}

So the code should be

```
User::create($request->all());

        $loginRequest             = new Login();
        $loginRequest['email']    = $request->get('email');
        $loginRequest['password'] = $request->get('password');



    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->get('email'), 
    'password' => $request->get('password')])) {
    return Redirect::route('dashboard');
   }
```